# Generate a JSON schema from multiple examples

Tags: web-apps, json

There are plenty of tools that will generate a JSON schema from data, such as https://jsonschema.net/home

But as far as I have found, these will generate a schema from just a single example.

What I want to do is generate a schema from multiple examples, and have it determine if they are optional, what multiple types there are etc.

I have raised an issue on the JSONSchema.net GitHub requesting this here: https://github.com/jsonsystems/json-schema/issues/91

Does anyone know of a tool, preferably online, that already does this?

As an aside - what terminology is useful for googling this kind of thing? ie. how do I differentiate between a tool that uses a json schema to generate something else (code, documentation), and a tool that generates the json schema itself?

Comment: If not "online", what "local OS" should be addressed here? Also, any price limit?

Answer (score 1):

This here is a Java based solution:

https://github.com/saasquatch/json-schema-inferrer

That has an online tool demoing it:

https://json-schema-inferrer.herokuapp.com/